# AgoraRTM Query Message History (Persistent Messaging)

Tags: agora.io

There is an option to persist messages on send on both [`RTMClient.sendMessageToPeer()`](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/classes/rtmclient.html#sendmessagetopeer) and [`RTMChannel.sendMessage()`](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/classes/rtmchannel.html#sendmessage) methods via the [SendMessagesOptions](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/interfaces/sendmessageoptions.html) interface (which is the optional second parameter on both methods).

However I cannot find information on how and in what form these messages are persisted, and ultimately on how to retrieve the messages history.

Can someone point me in the right direction please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the feature is still in beta.

This answer is from their official [repo](https://github.com/AgoraIO/RTM/issues/53) at GitHub.

> I confirmed with my colleagues, it's shown there but still in beta phase. if you believe you need this feature maybe you can try contacting sales person.